# SQL sort and count duplicate value

Tags: sql, count, pivot

I need to count and sort student, how many course they took based on level
like this:

```
ID|NAME |Point1|point 2|point 3|
1 | Tom |     3|   3   |   1   |
2 | Jer |     5|   0   |   6   |
```

I have 3 table
student,Course,Registration

Member:
student_id,student_name

Subject:
subject_id,point_score

Registration:
student_id,subject_id

What I currently have:

```
Select Max(m.student_id) AS 'ID', student_name AS 'Name',COUNT(point_score) as'level 1',
( select count(point_score) from Subject where point_score=2)as'point 2',
(select COUNT(point_score) from subject where point_score=3) as 'level 3'
from Student m inner join Registration r on m.student_id = r.student_id
inner join subject c on c.subject_id=r.subject_id
where point_score =1
group by student_name
Go
```

The problem with it, is that it only counts point 1 correctly and not point 2 and 3 and it doesn't display the user if they do not take any subject like this:

```
ID   NAME  Point1 Point2 Point3
1   |Tom  |     0|     0|    0
```

Comment: *Unrelated:* If you have members with the same name, do you truly want the *merge* the result of all the members with that name, and show the `mem_id` of the *last* member by that name? That sounds ... just ... *wrong!!!* --- I highly recommend you add `mem_id` as a second column to the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-selects in the result columns need to join through the `Registration` table too.

To see students who don't take any subject, change the joins in the main query to left outer joins, or, better yet, process point 1 the same way you process point 2 and 3.

*Using sub-queries*

```sql
SELECT m.student_id AS 'ID'
     , m.student_name AS 'Name'
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Registration r
           JOIN Subject c ON c.subject_id = r.subject_id
          WHERE r.student_id = m.student_id
            AND c.subject_level = 1
       ) AS 'point 1'
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Registration r
           JOIN subject c ON c.subject_id = r.subject_id
          WHERE r.student_id = m.student_id
            AND c.point_score = 2
       ) AS 'point 2'
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Registration r
           JOIN Subject c ON c.subject_id = r.subject_id
          WHERE r.student_id = m.student_id
            AND c.point_score = 3
       ) AS 'point 3'
  FROM Student m
```

*Using outer joins and group by*

```sql
SELECT m.student_id AS 'ID'
     , m.student_name AS 'Name'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN c.point_score = 1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Point 1'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN c.point_score = 2 THEN 1 END) AS 'Point 2'
     , SUM(CASE WHEN c.point_score = 3 THEN 1 END) AS 'Point 3'
  FROM Student m
  LEFT JOIN Registration r
  LEFT JOIN Subject c ON c.subject_id = r.subject_id
 GROUP BY m.student_name
        , m.student_id
```